# Is a stale session stopping post variables being submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, session, cookies

I have had this issue intermittently for some time, but I only just had it happen repeatedly enough to actually trouble shoot it. It happened repeatedly in FF but I have seen it in Chrome as well.

I have login form as below, it is very simple, email address and password and a submit button

```
    <form method="post" action="login.php" id="valid" class="mainForm">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="">
                <label for="req1">Email:</label>
                <div class="loginInput"><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" name="email" class="validate" id="req1" /></div>
                <div class="fix"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="">
                <label for="req2">Password:</label>
                <div class="loginInput"><input style="width: 100%;" type="password" name="password" class="validate" id="req2" /></div>
                <div class="fix"></div>
            </div>

            <input name="action" type="hidden" value="log_in" />

            <div class="">
                <div class=""><input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="remember_me" value="1"/><label>Remember me</label></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log me in" class="submitForm" />
                <div class="fix"></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Submitting the above form wouldn't log me in, it just displayed the login form again as if nothing was submitted. So I amended the `login.php` file that is submitted to, and at the very top added `print_r($_POST);`

When I submitted the form again all it displayed was an empty array. It was like the form variables just weren't being sent. I tried several accounts, and got a blank array each time.

I then tried to enter an email address that I new wasn't in the database, and to my amazement the $_POST array populated with the fake email and password. I then tried a real account again and it was blank.

The last thing I did was to deleted the session cookie in FF for the site, and then try again. To my surprise I could then log in OK. I logged in and out a few times after that with no problem at all!

So my question is: What was that session cookie doing to prevent the post variables from being sent (if that was what was actually happening) and why did it populate the $_POST array if I entered a fake email address? The `print_r($_POST)` I did was the very first thing in the script, before any other processing or includes, yet it still was empty??

I guess I don't really know how browsers deal with session cookies, but this behaviour has me completely clueless.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this, or general session advice.

**EDIT - PHP Code for the login.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
include '../inc/init.php';

$action = fRequest::get('action');

if ('log_out' == $action) {

    fSession::destroy();
    fAuthorization::destroyUserInfo();
    fMessaging::create('success', '<center>You were successfully logged out</center>');

}

if (fAuthorization::checkAuthLevel('user') || fAuthorization::checkAuthLevel('buser')) {
    fURL::redirect('index.php');
}


if ('log_in' == $action) {
    # Set session variables etc...
}
```

The `init.php` include at the top sets the database connetion strings and starts the session etc... I am using FlourishLib Un-Framework set of classes which includes a session class.

Thanks

Comment: It might help to actually show some of your PHP here.

Comment: I have added the php code for `Login.php`

Answer (score 0):

try this code please

```
$actions = array('log_in', 'log_out');
$action = fRequest::getValid('action', $actions);
if ($action == 'log_out') {
fSession::clear();
fAuthorization::destroyUserInfo();
fMessaging::create('success', URL_ROOT . 'index.php', 'You were successfully logged   out');
fURL::redirect(URL_ROOT . 'index.php');
}
if ($action == 'log_in') {
if (fRequest::isPost()) {
    try {
        $valid_login = fRequest::get('username') == 'yourlogin';
        $valid_pass = md5(fRequest::get('password')) == 'md5(youpassword)'; 
        if (!$valid_login || !$valid_pass) {
            throw new fValidationException('The login or password entered is invalid');
        }
        fAuthorization::setUserToken(fRequest::get('username'));
        fURL::redirect(fAuthorization::getRequestedURL(TRUE, URL_ROOT . 'index.php'));
    } catch (fExpectedException $e) {
        fMessaging::create('error', fURL::get(), $e->getMessage());
    }
}
include VIEWS_DIR . DS . basename(__FILE__);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am already doing everything in your script, with the exception of the `$actions` array and `fSession::clear();`. I do not see how these will help with my problem but I have added them any way and up date this answer with the outcome.